# Does ngAnimate look at CSS classes to determine animation length, or does it detect the `animationend` event?

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

Pretty much what the title says.

When adding/removing content from the DOM, ngAnimate will leave the element in the DOM until the animation is complete. I can't tell if it is looking at any `transition-duration` or `animation-duration` CSS properties, or if it is listening for the `animationend` event to destroy a leaving element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This comment](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate/blob/master/angular-animate.js#L37) at the top of the angular animate js source indicates it relies on the onanimationend event:

> If unprefixed events are not supported but webkit-prefixed are, use
>   the latter. Otherwise, just use W3C names, browsers not supporting
>   them at all will just ignore them.  Note: Chrome implements
>   `window.onwebkitanimationend` and doesn't implement
>   `window.onanimationend` but at the same time dispatches the
>   `animationend` event and not `webkitAnimationEnd`.

Although, if you read further down, it seems they are just using that event (and every other animation-related event) to check against their own internal timer [they get by parsing the css styles](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate/blob/master/angular-animate.js#L880) to see if the [animation is completed](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate/blob/master/angular-animate.js#L1239).

It seems the flow goes something like this: 1) search css for how long the animation should last, 2) register all animation events to a single onAnimationProgress function, 3) when onAnimationProgess is called, test if the event time is the same as their calculations say it should be, 4) mark complete and trigger close.

Comment: I know how to change the length of an animation. What I'm asking is 'How does AngularJS know when to remove an animated element? Does it base this on the CSS properties, or does it listen for the `animationend` event to destroy the animated content.

Both would accomplish the same thing, but it could affect the order of things happening.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I updated my answer with somewhat useful information.

Comment: Yup! that looks right! I followed it a bit further and found: https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate/blob/master/angular-animate.js#L1383.